# How to read JSON where the array is top-level?

Tags: android, html, arrays, json, root

I'm new to Android development but usually find the answer to my issues online. I've spent the whole weekend without success.

What I'm trying to do is read data from the JSON file on the internet.
It looks like this

```
[
{
    "id": "bitcoin", 
    "name": "Bitcoin", 
    "symbol": "BTC", 
    "rank": "1", 
    "price_usd": "9246.27", 
    "price_btc": "1.0", 
    "24h_volume_usd": "5659320000.0", 
    "market_cap_usd": "156378808114", 
    "available_supply": "16912637.0", 
    "total_supply": "16912637.0", 
    "max_supply": "21000000.0", 
    "percent_change_1h": "1.77", 
    "percent_change_24h": "-1.51", 
    "percent_change_7d": "-17.57", 
    "last_updated": "1520773466"
}]
```

It's just a single object in an array. Unfortunately, it's not up to me how it looks like.

What I am successful at doing is reading HTML and then finding the fields I'm looking for but I want to do it in a better way. I've watched tens of videos and read some tutorials online but I just can't make it work. I get exceptions, crashes and what not and out of the rage deleted it all and I am starting from scratch again. I know beginner questions are not usually welcomed so I don't ever ask anything myself. I'm just doing this little project for fun to learn some programming.

It would be cool if somebody could show or point me in the right direction. I literally can't even read the data if I'm approaching it as JSON and not HTML.

Comment: How do you try? where is your code?

Comment: "I get exceptions, crashes and whatnot and out of the rage deleted it all and am starting from scratch" -- you will have much better luck here if you provide a [mcve] showing something that you tried and explain what your symptoms are. Otherwise, we have nothing to go on. We do not know where this content is or how one might retrieve it. We do not know which JSON parser you wish to use (Gson, Jackson, `JsonReader`, `JSONArray`, etc.). We do not know what aspects of the problem are giving you difficulty. And so on.

Comment: I tried a lot of ways to do this and have not saved any of them because they are useless. I don't know what parsers are best. I just want to get the data. I've tried JSONArray for sure but as you can see usually the JSON files start with { and not [. Sorry that I can't help you help me.